# Merging a string splitted by space in Python

Tags: python, string, merge, split

I have a part of code like this:

```
for line in response.body.split("\n"):
    if line != "": 
        opg = int(line.split(" ")[2])
        opc = int(line.split(" ")[3])
        status = int(line.split(" ")[5])
        if command == 'IDENTIFY':
            if opg==opcodegroupr and opc==opcoder:
                if status=="0":
            IEEEAddrRemoteDev = line.split(" ")[6:14]
        ret['success'] = "IDENTIFY: The value is %s " % (IEEEAddrRemoteDev)
        self.write(tornado.escape.json_encode(ret))
        self.finish()
```

Variable 'line' is like this for example:

```
1363011361 2459546910990453036 157 0 17 0 209 61 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 201
```

I would for example take fields from 6 to 14 and "merging" each others to print IEEEAddrRemoteDev like a entire string.

Is this

```
IEEEAddrRemoteDev = line.split(" ")[6:14]
```

the correct way? If I write

```
print IEEEAddrRemoteDev
```

I don't obtain anything.

There's something wrong...

Comment: I don't know why you don't get anything, but joining strings is like this: `"".join(line.split(" ")[6:14])`

Comment: The reason you never get any output is that `if status=="0":` is never true, because you cast it to an `int`. See my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use `join`:

```
ret['success'] = "IDENTIFY: The value is %s " % (" ".join(IEEEAddrRemoteDev))
```

However, the bigger issue is that your `status=="0"` line is never true (because `status` is an int), change it to

```
if status == 0:
```

Comment: I doubt that this will fix the problem, given that `If I write print IEEEAddrRemoteDev I don't obtain anything`. I think OP has an empty `line` somewhere in the input and that's throwing off the algorithm

Comment: @inspectorG4dget that is a bit strange, but in that case only the empty line should have an empty output.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Sorted it out- the issue is his `if status == "0"` line, which means he never gets any output from the print statement at all because the condition is never met (status is an `int`).

Comment: Good call (+1)! I just saw your edit. Also, I noticed that OP has a syntax error, but that's more likely a copy-pasting error as the code won't run otherwise

Comment: Yes the error was status=="0". status is not a string is an int. The join method is right! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't completely understand your desired output.  But when you write the line:

```
IEEEAddrRemoteDev = line.split(" ")[6:14]
```

What you are doing is splitting the string by whitespace, so the output is currently:

```
['209', '61', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

I assume you want the following output?

```
'20961000000' ?
```

If so, just add the following line before your print statement:

```
"".join(IEEEAddrRemoveDev)
```